# how to best compare formulas?

Tags: r, formula

I'd like to be able to compare two formulas. I'm wondering about the advantages/disadvantages/pitfalls of using `identical()`, `==`, or equality of the deparsed formulas.

Consider e.g.

```
xx <- ~0
environment(xx) <- new.env()
```

- `xx == ~0` returns `TRUE`
- `identical(xx, ~0)` *and* `identical(xx, ~0, ignore.environment=TRUE)` return `FALSE` (the `ignore.environment` argument is *only applied when comparing closures*)
- `deparse(xx) == "~0"` returns `TRUE` (but deparsing is almost always a bad idea ...)

To try to be clear, I want the formulas to be *semantically* equivalent; I don't care about their environments.  It would be a bonus to be able to do formula expansion and ignore order of terms (e.g. so `~a*b` and `~b+a+a:b` would be equivalent), but that's too much of a rabbit hole to worry about. I will settle for `~a+b` and `~b+a` being non-equivalent, as long as `~a+b` (environment 1) and `~a+b` (environment 2) are the same.

It did occur to me to write a comparison function that replaces the environment of both values with `emptyenv()`, then using `identical()`, but that seemed convoluted.

Are there edge cases/reasons I shouldn't just use `==` here?

Comment: Maybe `all.equal(xx, ~0)`?

Comment: huh, interesting.  `all.equal.formula` uses `(!identical(deparse(target), deparse(current)))` internally (!).  I wonder what They know?

Comment: When `identical` returns `FALSE` I always try `all.equal`, it's much less strict.

Comment: What exactly would be the same to you? Formulas are just basically chunks of unevaluated code with environments. Different functions can interpret the functions however they like. Do you want to compare exact same symbols in exact same order with exactly the same environment? Maybe some examples of what you consider to be the same/different. I'm not sure what answer you want from your example.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, do you want to post this comment as an answer?

Comment: Done, I have also posted my second comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `identical` returns `FALSE` I always try `all.equal`, it's much less strict. Quoting its help page:

> `all.equal(x, y)` is a utility to compare R objects `x` and `y`
>   testing ‘near equality’. If they are different, comparison is still
>   made to some extent, and a report of the differences is returned.

```
xx <- ~0
environment(xx) <- new.env()

all.equal(xx, ~0)
#[1] TRUE
```

But in `if` statements this shouldn't be used as is, the right way would be `isTRUE(all.equal(.))`. Again from the documentation:

> Do not use `all.equal` directly in if expressions—either use
>   `isTRUE(all.equal(....))` or `identical` if appropriate.

```
isTRUE(all.equal(xx, ~0))
#[1] TRUE
```